# Featured Image Resolution not set

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add code for featured image on different resolution. like thumbnail, medium, large and full. But I wanna look like this type of resolution.
e.g
125x125 
150x150.
250x250
I am trying this code. but it's not work. 
`<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,array(300,300), true);?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x300" target="_blank">300x300</a>
</br>`

It's show full size of image.

Comment: Try with this one `wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,array(300,300),false)`

Comment: It's not working Mr. Syed Qarib. Please resolve this.

<?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,array(300,300), false);?> <a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x300" target="_blank">300x300</a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add different image sizes in your `functions.php` file.  WordPress will then create these resized images when a new image is created.

Usage is as such:

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

Lots more information available on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

If you wish to create these image sizes retrospectively (to images you've already added) then you'll need to regenerate your thumbnails.  You can do this using the [regenerate thumbnails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

You can then reference a image size in your code.  A full example:

Inside `functions.php`:

```
add_image_size( 'example_size', 200, 200, true );
```

Inside your theme:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'example_size', true );
```

Comment: it's not working. I am trying to add this php function into funtion.php

 
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
add_image_size( 'example_size', 300, 300, false );

and call 



<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'example_size', true );?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x300" target="_blank">300x300</a>
</br>
but it;

Comment: OK...?  So what's the issue

Comment: It's generate only medium, thumbnail, large and full size of image. not by 300x300, 450x450 etc. Please solve this issue. I am using this code.


<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, array(300,300), true );?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x300" target="_blank">300x300</a>

Comment: Please look at my answer, it goes through in detail what you need to do

Comment: I am using this code. but it's not work.
<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'example_size', true ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x125" target="_blank">300x125</a>
</br>